# Transform day of the year into DDMMYYYY with Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to calculate the day of the year, which I will get from a Object, transform to a DD/MM/YYYY format.
I have no clue how to do this.. Anyone has done this before?

Comment: Use Date filter check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, it is in Angular2

Comment: Use `pipes(|) selector`

Comment: Use a date pipe on your Date object.  `{{ myDate | date'dd/MM/yyyy' }}`   take a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html